# Combobox borderstyle

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Hi I have set the combobox control's flatstyle to flat.

**Is it possible to draw a border around this control?**

The control does not have a borderstyle property. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Side note: I wish to keep the flatstyle flat if at all possible.

Comment: The control's parent could draw a border around it in its Paint event handler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put it in a panel, set Border on panel, Put cmb box in panel, set cmb box to dock fill and Border style flat.simple but not so elegant solution.

Comment: This is sufficient for my purposes thanx so much!

Answer (score 15):

Create custom ComboBox control, and override it's `WndProc` method. You can easily draw a border with [ControlPaint.DrawBorder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawborder.aspx) method:

```
public class ComboBoxWithBorder : ComboBox
{
    private Color _borderColor = Color.Black;
    private ButtonBorderStyle _borderStyle = ButtonBorderStyle.Solid;
    private static int WM_PAINT = 0x000F; 

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT)
        {
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle);
            Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, bounds, _borderColor, _borderStyle);
        }
    }

    [Category("Appearance")]
    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get { return _borderColor; }
        set 
        { 
            _borderColor = value;
            Invalidate(); // causes control to be redrawn
        }
    }

    [Category("Appearance")]
    public ButtonBorderStyle BorderStyle
    {
        get { return _borderStyle; }
        set 
        { 
            _borderStyle = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }     
}
```

*BTW* There is also overloaded DrawBorder method, which allows to set width of border. Use it if you need.

Comment: Does this work?  A ComboBox borders can't be overwritten in the paint event.  I think you have to override WndProc and look for the non-client paint message.  Of course, then it flickers rather ugly.

Comment: @HansPassant sorry, didn't have an ability to run it on VS. Now all is verified and working